# How do I plot SRTM source Raster with cartopy?

Tags: python, matplotlib, gis, cartopy

I have been looking at the options offered by cartopy to do rapid automatic maps. I found the SRTMSource to be very convenient. However, I have'nt found how to plot the data using a different projection such as mercator...

When I do:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cartopy.io.srtm import SRTM3Source

source = SRTM3Source

plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.add_raster(source())
ax.set_extent([12, 13, 47, 48])
plt.show()()
```

It works just fine and do a plot using the PlateCarree projection

But When I try to change the projection of the axes to Mercator:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cartopy.io.srtm import SRTM3Source

source = SRTM3Source

plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Mercator())
ax.add_raster(source())
ax.set_extent([12, 13, 47, 48])
plt.show()()
```

I get an error that says:

```
Unsupported projection for the SRTM3 source.
```

So is there a way to keep the SRTMSource fonctionality (automatic download) and plot the raster using any projection?

I thought of simply doing an imshow and change the projection but as the data of a RasterSource are retrieved at plotting time, I don't know how to do it...

```
plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Mercator())
ax.imshow(source(), transform=ccrs.Mercator())
ax.set_extent([12, 13, 47, 48])
plt.show()
```

return a TypeError.

Comment: Just realised that the title was not accurate... It misses the projection issue...sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I'm trying to learn more about cartopy, and I think I can answer this question now, maybe this could help others with a similar problem.

Okay here we go. First, there is a good explanation of the difference of transform and projection on the cartopy Homepage:
https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/tutorials/understanding_transform.html?highlight=understanding

The projection keyword determines how the plot will look, so for this problem here, we change the projection to Mercator:

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Mercator())

You can choose any projection you like, but you have to add the transform Keyword (and this is still PlateCarree in this case, because the DATA is provided in PlateCarree):

ax.set_extent([12, 13, 47, 48],transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

So the correct code would be:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cartopy.io.srtm import SRTM3Source

source = SRTM3Source

plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Mercator())
ax.add_raster(source())
ax.set_extent([12, 13, 47, 48], transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
plt.show()()
```

I hope this is correct and my explanation is helpful.